# my css wont link with my html, what am i doing wrong?

Tags: php, html, css

I just now"run code snippet"here on stackoverflow and css works but when i open the index.html doc in my folder it wont show any color, weird. can someone pleas help thanks.

[image: Screenshot]

[image: Screenshot 2]

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.thumbnail-title {
  background: rgb(96, 125, 139);
  color: rgb(202, 238, 139);
  display: block;
  font-size: 50px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 4px 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  
 <link rel="stylesheets" href="styles.css">
  <h1>ottergram</h1>
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon-32x32.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon-16x16.png">
  <link rel="manifest" href="/site.webmanifest">
  <link rel="mask-icon" href="/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">
  <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
 </html>
```

Comment: Have you checked to make sure it is the correct file path?

Comment: If your codes works in your snippet but not in your browser, its probably cache related.

Comment: Is your css file in the same folder as your html?

Comment: @MrBuggy & Richard In the picture in his question it shows that styles.css is in the same folder as his index.html.

Comment: It is very likely a cache problem.

Comment: @Granny Yes I see his bug, it's a typo

Comment: @D.Pardal Nope, It's because of his typo in the rel attribute of the link he writes stylesheets with an "s" at the end in case of stylesheet...

Comment: Lol. Sometimes happens.

Comment: @MrBuggy thanks guys reallyyy appreciate your help, felt pretty dumb when I found out it was just because of the "s" lol. Thanks again

Comment: @EricLopez you can mark my answer below as correct :P cheers

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo right there: `<link rel="stylesheets" href="styles.css">`

it's `rel="stylesheet"` **without the letter "s"** not like you did `rel="stylesheets"`.

So simply take this one: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="stylesheets" href="styles.css">
```

stylesheet**s** wont work, only stylesheet!

Answer (score -1):

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">`
Please change your external css reference with this one.

Answer (score -2):

If you do not use the canonical links to downloadable resources, be sure that the paths of the downloaded files and your current URL are written correctly.
For example:

Current URL:
http://exapmle.com/test/
**Use ..**

```
<link rel="mask-icon" href="../safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">
```

Use full URL:
http://exapmle.com/test/

```
<link rel="mask-icon" href="http://exapmle.com/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">
```